# Angular 2 radio button ngmodel not works as expected

Tags: angular, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons with ngmodel. The `downloadVal` is initialized in typescript file with xls.  So by default when the page loads the xls option should be selected

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="downloadxls"></label>
    <input id="downloadxls"  name="downloadVal" [(ngModel)]="downloadVal" type="radio" value="xls" aria-describedby="xlsDescription"> XLS

    <label for="downloaddoc"></label>
    <input id="downloaddoc"  name="downloadVal" [(ngModel)]="downloadVal" type="radio" value="doc" aria-describedby="docDescription"> Document
</fieldset>
```

Everything is working fine in local setup. When its deployed in server, by default the xls radio button is not selected. Also the html looks like below.

```
<input aria-describedby="xlsDescription" data-angular2-attrb-value1="downloadVal" data-angular2-attrb1="[(ngModel)]" id="downloadxls" name="downloadVal" type="radio" value="xls">
```

Comment: I suggest adding more info. Please show some of the typescript. Is there anything in the console?

Comment: In typescript file, I have initialized like this. scheduleDownload = 'xls'. No error message also in console.

Answer (score 0):

I have been adding this to the inputs for safeguard. Seemed to fix some problems.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="downloadVal" [selected]="downloadVal"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.. There is some issue in AEM deployment. Its resolved.. Nothing wrong in Angular code